# Ext.Messagebox issue with Sencha Touch 2.0 in iOS 9

Tags: sencha-touch-2, mobile-safari, ios9

I have created an iPad app in Sencha Touch 2.0.0 which has been working perfectly on iOS 8 & iOS 7. But after upgrading to iOS 9, anything after the overlays just breaks/freezes the app.

I have found that the latest version of Sencha Touch doesn't have this problem. But due to some performance issues, sencha Touch's latest version can not be used in our app.

The issue exists in the components like Messagebox, date picker, Action sheet etc.

Could anyone please suggest me a solution for this ?

Many thanks

Comment: so did you checked any warning or errors on console.

Comment: There is no warning and errors in console. There is a live example of this issue which is on the sencha touch kitchen sink. Please use the below link on iPad safari and navigate to User interface > Overlays. press any buttons on this page and we can see that the overlay is not hiding in 2.0.1 version.

Kitchen sink 2.0.1 
http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.0.1/examples/kitchensink/

Kitchen sink 2.4.1 
http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.4.1/examples/kitchensink/

The issue shows in 2.0.1 and it does not exists in the 2.4.1 version

Comment: so you can update your application in 2.4

Comment: I have already done this. But ST 2.4  causing some other performance  related issues which was not in 2.0. That's the reason why i couldn't use the latest version.

Comment: I have the same kinds of problems, specifically anything using a background mask, such as pickers, message boxes, etc, as the mask doesn't clear afterwards, but also  with nested lists, with only the first tap being recognised etc. I'm going to take the upgrade route to 2.4. What kinds of issues did you have to overcome? - I know you want to fix the issues in 2.0, but you did say you tried 2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, for me it worked:

```
Ext.override(Ext.Component, {
hide: function (animation) {
    if (!this.getHidden()) {
        this.setHidden(true);
    }
    return this;
}});
```

Inspired by: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262324-Sencha-Messagebox-and-Overlay-Problems-on-HTC-One-Browser

Comment: This is worked. Thank you so much for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking this on Chrome latest version. If yes then this is the issue of Chrome latest version. You can check Kitchen sink touch 2.0.1 example on IE and it's working fine.

Comment: Sorry,  this wont help me because my sencha touch app is running in iPad which is compiled with cordova.